# A non index-oriented way to search for unique values between two lists in R

Tags: r, indexing, unique

Lets say I have a section of a list that looks like this:

```
aaa[[1]]
# [1] "A5-5,73"  "B3-4,73"  "E3-8,73"  "A1-8,73"  "C1-7,73"  "A1-2,73"  "C3-2,73"  "C1-1,73"
```

Lets say I have another list with a section that looks like this:

```
bbb[[1]]
# [1] "B3-4,73"  "C3-2,73"  "A5-5,73"  "A1-8,73"  "A1-2,73"  "A1-5,73"  "B1-1,73"  "C1-4,73"
```

Consider that I now run

```
which(aaa[[1]]!= bbb[[1]])
```

which returns

```
# [1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  8
```

This is technically true, because the index `[4]` is the same in both `aaa` and `bbb`

**What I would like to have returned is:**

```
# [1] "C1-7,73"  "A1-2,73" "C1-1,73"
```

because these are the values of `aaa` that are not in `bbb` regardless of position. I would also be open to a solution that would just provide an index number, such as:

```
# [1] 5 6 8
```

**Here is a reproducible example:**

```
aaa <- vector("list")
aaa[[1]] <- c("A5-5,73",  "B3-4,73",  "E3-8,73",  "A1-8,73",
          "C1-7,73",  "A1-2,73",  "C3-2,73",  "C1-1,73")
bbb <- vector("list")
bbb[[1]] <- c("B3-4,73",  "C3-2,73",  "A5-5,73",  "A1-8,73",
          "A1-2,73",  "A1-5,73",  "B1-1,73",  "C1-4,73")
```

Comment: I think you want `setdiff()`, as in `setdiff(aaa[[1]], bbb[[1]])`

Comment: And what you want returned doesn't match the data. `E3-8,73` instead of `A1-2,73`, yes?

Comment: Both comments above are correct. I was not aware of `setdiff`

Comment: @RichardScriven Make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare every element of the list `aaa` with the corresponding element `bbb` simply do.

```
mapply(FUN = setdiff, x = aaa, y = bbb)
```

---

<sub>While writing this I saw `setdiff` was mentioned already in the comments by @RichardScriven.</sub>

Comment: Nice guess that the OP would want to do this elementwise on the lists (assuming that's actually correct...), I wondered why that wasn't simplified.

Comment: @Richard Scriven Well, thanks, but that's not fair, you came up with the solution first.

Comment: If I wanted to post an answer, I would have done so.  Really, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

As @Richard Scriven mentioned in his comment

```
setdiff(aaa[[1]], bbb[[1]])
```

is the way to get the elements. As you also asked for an index number, you could use which()

```
which(aaa[[1]] %in% setdiff(aaa[[1]], bbb[[1]]))
```

While %in% produces logical values, which() tells where they are TRUE.

Comment: No need for the setdiff in the second one, it's just `which(! a %in% b)`